# Best lightweight non-html WYSIWYG for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wysiwyg

Since a few days I'm looking for a non-html (markdown, bbcode) WYSIWYG really minimalist for a kind of forum.

I just need to allow users to add links, bold italic and break line in a non html way. 
But all I can found is some dirty old wysiwyg with too many functionality and without directives for angularjs or just html wysiwyg..

Do you have any suggestions ?

At this time I'm thinking that I should make it by myself.

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this [example](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/QbLLGW) implemented in AngularJs; You can customise and convert it into Angular module as per your need;

**Example**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("click", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind("click", function () {
                    scope.$evalAsync(attrs.click);
                });
            }
        };
    })
    .controller("Example", function ($scope) {
        $scope.supported = function (cmd) {
            var css = !!document.queryCommandSupported(cmd.cmd) ? "btn-succes" : "btn-error"
            return css
        };
        $scope.icon = function (cmd) {
            return (typeof cmd.icon !== "undefined") ? "fa fa-" + cmd.icon : "";
        };
        $scope.doCommand = function (cmd) {
            if ($scope.supported(cmd) === "btn-error") {
                alert("execCommand(“" + cmd.cmd + "”)\nis not supported in your browser");
                return;
            }
            val = (typeof cmd.val !== "undefined") ? prompt("Value for " + cmd.cmd + "?", cmd.val) : "";
            document.execCommand(cmd.cmd, false, (cmd.val || ""));
        }
        $scope.commands = commands;
        $scope.tags = [
    'Bootstrap', 'AngularJS', 'execCommand'
  ]
    })
```